# Add lines in HTML texarea

Tags: css, html

Is is possible to add lines in html textarea. When I say lines I mean something like lines in paper notebook. Something like this:

---

---

---

---

---

Comment: What browsers are you targeting ? do you only plan to support html5 + css3 only or css2 + html4

Comment: Only Chrome, all versions of html and css are supported

Comment: Have you considered using an image background?

Comment: Yes, but it must be only CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea class="paperlines"></textarea>
```

**CSS:**

```
.paperlines
{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -ms-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), -o-linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(right, white 10px, transparent 10px), linear-gradient(white 30px, #ccc 30px, #ccc 31px, white 31px);
    background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 31px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    line-height: 31px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    padding: 8px;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
}
.paperlines:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

**Jsfiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/7kteksez/

---

**EDITED:** added another example for a better scrolling method

Add the following to the `paperlines` class

http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/7kteksez/1/

```
background-attachment: local;
```

Comment: when it's to scroll, lines should follow, not?

Comment: Lines should follow the text

Answer (score 0):

Create a image like one line using some basic image tools and add it as `background` to text area

Add CSS :

```
textarea {
 background: url('path of image') repeat-y;
}
```

Note: make image with height correspondingly to font you are going to use in text area

Hope it helps